# How to bundle prop types in a reusable React component library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to make a simple React components library for fun using Typescript and Storybook, and my first silly `Button` component seems to work. I have another CRA demo app where I am trying the library as a final user.

I am stuck with a thing though: I can't make the `prop-types` of my `Button` component to work in the demo application. It just doesn't print the warnings.

### Some additional details:

Files and folder of the library are currently organized as follows:

```
src/
  index.ts
  controls/
    index.ts
    Button.tsx
babelconfig.js
tsconfig.ts
webpack.config.js

(+ other configuration files and folder for jest and storybook)
```

I have an `src/index.ts` file which is the entry point of my library and it just exports everything that comes from the `controls` folder.

```js
// src/index.ts
export * from './controls'
```

In my `src/controls` folders there's an `index.ts` file which exports everything from the `Button` component.

```js
// src/controls/index.ts
export * from './Button'
```

The `Button` component, at the moment, is as simple as:

```js
import React from 'react'
import t, { InferProps } from 'prop-types'

const propTypes = {
  text: t.string.isRequired
}

const Button = ({ text }: InferProps<typeof propTypes>) => (
  <button>
    { text }
  </button>
)

Button.propTypes = propTypes

export { Button }
```

Everything is bundled with `webpack 4.41` with this configuration file:

```js
// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    library: 'sads-ui',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  externals: [
    'react'
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.tsx', '.js' ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My `babel` configuration is this one:

```js
// babel.config.js

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-react',
    '@babel/preset-typescript'
  ],
  env: {
    test: {
      plugins: [ 'require-context-hook' ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if it may matter, but this is my `typescript 3.7` configuration file:

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ],
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

The main properties of my `package.json` file are these one:

```
// other properties

"main": "dist/index.js",
"files": [
  "dist/*",
  "!dist/**/*.stories.d.ts"
],
"scripts": {
  "prebuild": "rimraf ./dist ./*.tgz",
  "build": "webpack",
  "prepack": "npm run build",
  "test": "jest",
  "storybook": "start-storybook"
},

// other properties
```

### Expectations

In my demo app, created with `npx create-react-app sadsui-demo`, I installed the package in my `package.json` with a dependency like this:

```
// package.json

"sads-ui": "file:../sads-ui/sads-ui-0.1.0.tgz"
```

I use the `Button` in my `App.js` as follow:

```js
import React from 'react'

import { Button } from 'sads-ui'

const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <Button />
  </div>
)

export default App
```

I would expect to get a warning the tells me that the `text` prop of `Button` is required, but I get nothing. An empty button is correctly shown though.

### My reasoning

I'm somehow in the dark but I have something in mind, not sure if it makes any sense, also because it doesn't seem to work either.

I think that building the library in `webpack` `production` mode may strip off `prop-types` from the library bundle thus I don't have them available when I use the components in final applications.

I tried to bundle in `development` mode, I see in the `dist/index.js` the `prop-types` code but they aren't working no matter what... :(

Comment: Hey @0xc14m1z did you happen to figure out what you need to do for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not 

Answer (score 1):

Your webpack is compiling (everything matching *.tsx) to javascript when building the library, and when you import it into your create-react-app it is just javascript (you should go into your `/node_modules/` in your create-react-app and actually see for yourself what your library looks like)

In your library, you can export separate `index.d.ts` (or `Button.d.ts` or whatever) files for your components that are not compiled to JS that consumers can import 
(Always good to look at other projects and see how they do it. [Here is material ui's](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/material-ui/index.d.ts) `index.d.ts`, you can probably be a lot cleaner than that by having a Button.d.ts that is imported into the index.d.ts and then exported as one big library typescript module

Comment: Can you give me an example of full flow. The material ui's index is not clear at all.